# Cannot read property 'send' of undefined: Discord bot making a channel and sending a message to it then reacting to it

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I am trying to make a bot which sends an embedded message to a channel and then reacts to it. The channel that it sends to is created by the discord bot so I don't have the ID of the channel, just the name which is simply `island-info-\<user ID>`. This channel is created when you run command `/channel` but will soon be changed to when you join the server and deleted when you leave. When i run this code:

```
else if (cmd === `${prefix}channel`){
    const name = "island-info-" + message.author.username.toLowerCase();
    message.guild.channels.create(name, {
        type: 'text',
        permissionOverwrites: [
        {
            id: message.guild.id, 
            deny: ["VIEW_CHANNEL", "SEND_MESSAGES"]
        },
        {
            id: message.author.id,
            allow: ["VIEW_CHANNEL", "ADD_REACTIONS"]
        },
        ],
        parent: "734170209107051074"
    })
    .catch(console.error);
    const Embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle('ISLAND INFO')
    message.guild.channels.cache.find(r => r.name === name).send(Embed)
    message.guild.channels.cache.find(r => r.name === name).messages.fetch({ limit: 1 }).then(messages => {
        messages.first().react("")
    }).catch(err => {
        console.error(err)
    })
    }
```

It throws the error: `Cannot read property 'send' of undefined` which is because of the line `message.guild.channels.cache.find(r => r.name === name).send(Embed)`. Is there a better way of doing this because when i take the `cache` part out it says `find` isn't a command. **Thank you!**

(**EDIT**) I believe this is happening because it is sending the message to the channel at the same time or before it creates the channel, for a reason i dont know of, does anyone know a way around this because when I access the channel after the last `}` it works all fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is undefined then it means the channel you need with that name does not exist.
I don't know how in your situation you would handle this, but this is an option:

```
const Embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
  .setTitle('ISLAND INFO');
const channel = message.guild.channels.cache.find(r => r.name === name);
if (!channel) message.channel.send("Your channel does not exist!");
else {
  channel.send(embed)
}
```

Another thing to watch out for when storing data by username is that usernames can be changed. I suggest you name your channels by user id, as these do not change ever

Comment: The problem is that when I add in the line with the ".send" it doesn't create the channel, when I take that part out, it makes the channel all fine. I think it is, for some reason, sending the message at the same time as it creates the channel so it doesn't exist yet. Do you know a way around this (about to edit question to add this detail)

Comment: @CR9GAMING https://gist.github.com/DiamondMiner88/a66e9016500946ee987c369567ef4697

Comment: Hey thank you, because that nearly works, it now sends a message to the channel but then doesn't react and throws up the similar error of "Cannot read property 'react' of undefined"

Comment: channel.send(embed).then(message => message.react('whatever');

Comment: OMG Thank you so much! Life saver

Answer (score 1):

The channel does not exist at the time that you're trying to send a message to it.

You're using `.then()` and `.catch()` so you must have some awareness of promises. Remember that the action that a promise represents **is not finished** anywhere except inside the promise callback (or after if you use `await`).

Basically you're writing this:

```
//send a request to Discord to make a channel
message.guild.channels.create(name, {...}).catch(console.error);
...
//immediately, without waiting for Discord to make the channel, send a message to it
message.guild.channels.cache.find(r => r.name === name).send(Embed);
```

Your code to send a message *depends* on the channel having already been created. Thus, it **needs** to be in the `.then()` callback of the `channels.create(...)` promise. This has the additional advantage that the promise will actually resolve with the channel object, so you can call `.send()` on it instead of needing to search the cache.

```
message.guild.channels.create(name, {...}).then(chan => {
  //make embed
  chan.send(Embed);
}).catch(console.error);
```

You will need to similarly attach a `.then()` to the `.send()` call to react to the message that was just sent. Because you need to wait for Discord to actually make the message before you can react to it.